# THREE.JS : Rotate everyting (including camera) despite the orbit controller

Tags: javascript, three.js

Here is what I would like to do:

When a condition is verified, I would like to rotate everything on the scene, including the camera.

The user will not remark any difference since the camera still show exactly the same thing, but in fact the objects would be rotated.

Of course the orbit controller should still work...

The question might be silly, but I'm having troubles. Either the camera gets shifted and doesn't show the exact same thing or the orbit controller doesn't work.

How would you do?

Thanks.

**EDIT:** I should detail more what I tried.

So let's say the only thing I have on my scene is a cube with a number on each face.

- Face 1 is pointing toward +X.
- Face 2 is pointing toward +Y.
- Face 3 is pointing toward +Z.
- Face -1 is pointing toward -X.
- Face -2 is pointing toward -Y.
- Face -3 is pointing toward -Z.

At some point in my code, I want the cube to rotate without the user knowing.

- Face 1 should still point toward +X.
- Face -1 should still point toward -X.

But :

- Face 2 should point toward +Z.
- Face -2 should point toward -Z.
- Face 3 should point toward -Y.
- Face -3 should point toward +Y.

Ok?

But I don't want the user to notice this rotation.
So I wanted to rotate the camera at the exact same time in order to hide the fact that the cube rotated.

**What I tried:**

when I want to rotate X :

```
cube.rotateX(direction * Math.PI / 2);
camera.position.set(camera.position.x, direction * (-camera.position.z), direction * camera.position.y);
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

and when I want to rotate Y :

```
cube.rotateY(-direction * Math.PI / 2);
camera.position.set((-direction) * camera.position.z, camera.position.y, -direction * (-camera.position.x));
camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0));
```

Sadly, although it works for the Y rotation, it does not work for the X rotation, because the camera.up will fuck it up and make it look like there was a rotation around the Y axis.

How should I do ?

Comment: Rotating everything in the scene about the origin would only affect the world matrices of the objects within it. If that's what you're trying to do, OK. But we're going to need more to go on. Please share your code, and indicate what you've tried so far to accomplish the effect you're seeking. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: You are right. I edited to add more info.

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a `THREE.Group` and add everything in your current scene to it (your cube, camera, lights, etc.). Then rotate the group.

```
var group = new THREE.Group();
group.add(yourCube);
group.add(yourLight);
group.add(yourCamera);
scene.add(group);
// later...
group.rotateN(90 * Math.PI / 180); // whatever rotation function you choose to use
```

Anything you add to the group from this point on will use the group's coordinate system. Anything added to the scene will continue to use the standard world coordinate system.

If you rotate the group again, anything inside the group will rotate along with it, but anything in the scene will remain in place.